# Broken design when editing my communities list via the app

Tags: bug, android-app, communities-list

When I tap the "EDIT" under "Your Sites", each element in the subscription list that appears has an enormous margin at the top & bottom, which makes the list unusable.

Screenshot:

> [image]

- App Version: 1.0.85
- Device Manufacturer: Sony
- Device Model: SGP771
- OS Version: 6.0.1 (1994651638)

Comment: What subscription list? No list appears when editing via the app. Please clarify what you mean, and better post a screenshot.

Comment: Added screenshot

Comment: I see now, edited to make it more clear.